# PMF of busy period of a discrete-time M/M/1 queue

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, queueing-theory, birth-death-process

Consider a birth-death Markov chain, whose state space is $X=0,1,\ldots$ with the transition probabilities $P_{i,i+1}=p, P_{i+1,i}=q>p, \forall i\geq 0$. $P_{0,0}=1-p$ and $P_{i,i}=1-p-q, i>0$. Can I determine the (closed-form) probability mass function (PMF) of the first-passage time from state $1$ to $0$?

It seems that this first-passage time has close relationship to the busy period time of a discrete-time M/M/1 queue. It is known that the probability density function (PDF) of busy period of an (continuous-time) M/M/1 queue with arrival rate $\lambda$ and mean service time $1/\mu$ is given by
$$
f(t)=\frac{1}{t\sqrt{\rho}}e^{-(\lambda+\mu)t}I_1(2t\sqrt{\lambda\mu}),
$$
where $\rho=\lambda/\mu$. The mean and variance of the busy period time are $1/(\mu-\lambda)$ and $\frac{1+\rho}{\mu^2(1-\rho)^3}$, respectively.

To what extent can the classical M/M/1 results be applied in the discrete-time scenario? I found that the (empirical) mean first-passage time from state $1$ to $0$ is indeed $1/(q-p)$. Can someone please point me to some references for a detail treatment of such a discrete-time case?

Comment: There are lots of results for such random walks on integers. Queueing theory is just an application field. So i'd recommend to dig into the works of William Feller. They are readily available online. Yet other sources are available as well. The first search gave  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304414991900339